# How to get selected row data from nested row in Jqwidgets

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqwidget

I am using JqWidgets to generate nested grid. In my grid I am having context menu.

Here is my Nested grid details:
To show team, associated users information.

Now my target is to get id column value when user will click any option from context menu.

I tried no of approach to get it. But **each time it is returning undefined.** 
Can you please help me to find it ?

**Below is my attempts**

**Approach-1**

```
jQuery("#teamMenu").on('itemclick', function (event) { 
           var args = event.args;
           var rowindex = jQuery("#teamGrid").jqxGrid('getselectedrowindex');
           if (jQuery.trim(jQuery(args).text().trim()) == "View Details") {

             editrow = rowindex;
             jQuery("#rowId").val(editrow);
                var dataRecord = jQuery("#teamGrid").jqxGrid('getrowdata', editrow);
                alert('teamId: '  +data.teamId); // here I am getting undefined
        }
}
```

**Approach-2**

```
jQuery("#teamMenu").on('itemclick', function (event) { 
           var args = event.args;
           var rowindex = jQuery("#teamGrid").jqxGrid('getselectedrowindex');
           if (jQuery.trim(jQuery(args).text().trim()) == "View Details") {

             editrow = rowindex;
             jQuery("#rowId").val(editrow);
                var selectedRowData = jQuery('#teamGrid').jqxGrid('getrowdata', getselectedrowindexes[0]);
                alert('teamId: ' +  selectedRowData.teamId); // here I am getting undefined
        }
}
```

**Approach-3**

```
jQuery("#teamMenu").on('itemclick', function (event) { 
           var args = event.args;
           var rowindex = jQuery("#teamGrid").jqxGrid('getselectedrowindex');
           if (jQuery.trim(jQuery(args).text().trim()) == "View Details") {

             editrow = rowindex;
             jQuery("#rowId").val(editrow);
                var selectedRowData = jQuery('#teamGrid').jqxGrid('getrowdata', event.args.rowindex);
                alert('teamId: ' +  selectedRowData.teamId); // each time I am getting 1st reord ID value
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue in program

when use try to get selectedrowindex `jQuery("#teamGrid").jqxGrid('getselectedrowindex')` it's always return `-1`.

in my case I have set `selectionmode: 'multiplecellsadvanced'`

after remove this it's start working and `jQuery("#teamGrid").jqxGrid('getselectedrowindex')` returning select row index